# Cakephp how to reduce number of rows displayed with the Multiple Select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, multipleselection

I have a HABTM relation and when i use the following code. the Multiple Select is pretty long in size. i wanna know how to reduce the size.

```
<label for="checkbox">Cuisines:</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Cuisine', array('label' => false, 'div'=> false, 'class' => 'short')); ?>
```

[image]

I am not finding any option to reduce this size. should i do it with CSS only ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select { height: 210px;}
```

worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the "size" attribute.

```
<label for="checkbox">Cuisines:</label>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Cuisine', array('label' => false, 'div'=> false, 'size' => 3)); ?>
```